# vue data variables are undefined in method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web

I'm working with Vue and making a game and when getting the data for said game, some variables that I have defined in data are being returned undefined. Here's the code:

```
data() {
    return {
      receivedGame: undefined,
      allSteps: [],
}
```

```
methods: {

     async gameData() {
     const response = await fetch(`...`);

        const responseData = await response.json();

        this.receivedGame = responseData.steps; //returns correct data

        responseData.steps.map((step) => {
          this.allSteps.push({ //returns error, allSteps is undefined
            type: step.type,
          });
        });
 }
}
```

Comment: as arrow function always refer to parent scope. You can remove the arrow function and try. `responseData.steps.map(function(step) { ....... });`

Comment: I've done that and the allSteps array still comes back as undefined, even doing a ```console.log()```  of it in ```created()``` gives me back undefined instead of an empty array

Comment: Then this could be a `typo` issue. Can you please check and debug

Comment: I've triple checked for typos and there isn't any. I don't know what's going on with this page, I can't even ```console.log()``` any variable no matter the type, they all come back as undefined

Comment: In mounted(), If you just try to console `this.allSteps`. What are you getting ?

Comment: I'm just getting ```undefined```

Comment: can you please create a sample demo in jsfiddle or codepen. So that we can look into that and try to find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` hook must be a function that returns an object. Here you don't return anything!

```js
data() {
  return {
    receivedGame: undefined,
    allSteps: [],
  }
}
```

Comment: I do have return on data, that is not the problem I just forgot to write it here on the question, its fixed now

Comment: Is your `gameData` function written under `methods {}` attribute?

Comment: yes it is, forgot to write that as well

Comment: Please paste your entire component or create a reproduction on codepen. We're helpless here without a proper code sample.